# ROWID and expdp

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

Can anyone please tell me if `ROWID` is also exported in `expdp` process ans stored in dumpfile.

Can I use the following while importing?

```
QUERY=table_name:\"WHERE rowid = (select min(rowid) from table_name)\"
```

to import only certain rowid?

Answer (score 1):

`ROWID` is the "physical" location of a row, including the internal ID of the object, file number, block number, and position in the block. This is just a pseudocolumn, and it is not exported. It is not even stored in the database. When you move a table, ROWIDs change.

So no, do not use the above.

[ROWID Pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/ROWID-Pseudocolumn.htm#SQLRF00254)

> ...
>   If you delete and reinsert a row with the Import and Export utilities, for example, then its rowid may change. 
>   ...